# The Great Scifi Universe Popularity Contest

Tags: support, discussion

Perhaps there's already a related meta in the past, but there's been a lot of activity over the last couples in Star Wars-land.

It would be interesting if one of the members knowledgeable on data.stackexchange.com to write a query to compare the question counts for HP vs. ST vs. SW vs. Marvel vs. DCU.

Ideally it would be maintained as new tags for those universes are created.
And even better if we can plot the number of questions over time.

Answer (score 2):

> a query to compare the question counts for HP vs. ST vs. SW vs. Marvel vs. DCU

How about ... [the tags page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags)?

Maybe I'm misunderstanding you somehow, but it seems to me that that gives you all the information you want, updated live.

[image: tags]

Comment: Can it plot the rise in questions over time? I mean other than writing them down somewhere and comparing them later?

Comment: Yeah, freehand red circles are kosher, but *freehand red plots and graphs* are even better. -1 if the plots are not freehand

Comment: It's impossible to measure DC and Marvel that way, since we use these tags only for respective companies' properties as a whole. Their stuff gets tagged according to the work in question, with bunch of other tags, so it's a mess.

Comment: Yes,  I was suggesting that it would be necessary to create queries with all the tags that the questions might have.   It's not enough to look at the tags you circled.   For example,  there are certainly a lot of questions tagged [star-trek-tng] or [superman] or [rogue-one] not included.

Comment: Remember my star trek tags post? And people are tagging fantastic beasts without Harry Potter, and Rogue One without Star Wars...  Trouble.

Comment: @Mithrandir [Five](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantastic-beasts+-harry-potter) is probably few enough to edit in one go, for the former. [None](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rogue-one+-star-wars) of the latter.

Comment: We I manually edited the latter ones recently